# How to get image from sdcard in android?

Tags: android, imageview

i want create simple app in which i want get the image from sdcard but can`t success.
my code is below

```
File myFile = new File("/sdcard/photo.jpg");
ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myFile.getAbsolutePath());
jpgView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

but can`t get the image.

Comment: You have to use jpgView.setImageBitmap(d), instead of jpgView.setImageBitmap(d).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use below code instead of your code.

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/photo.jpg");
ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: For the directory, may i know must be **mnt**

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.example.facebook;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Facebookhome extends Activity {
    Button share;
    Uri screenshotUri;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebookhome);
        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there will definitely help you are is much simpler approach

**Java Version:**

```
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

private Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri filePath;

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GET_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GET_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Kotlin Version:**

```
import android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK

private val GET_IMAGE = 1
private lateinit var filePath : Uri
private lateinit var bitmap : Bitmap

private fun selectImage() {
    var photoPickerIntent : Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*")
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GET_IMAGE)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == GET_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        filePath = data.data

        try{
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity!!.contentResolver, filePath)
            imageView!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }catch (exception : IOException){
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Error Loading Image!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```